# Problems with authorization

Tags: python, request, authorization

I have problems with authorization in python. I want automatic enter to website, but i can't. I used many libraries: Grab, urlib2, request, but i never entered(
For check myself i enter pege with account data
It's real site, login and password

```
URL="http://pin-im.com/accounts/login/"
LOGIN="testuser"
PASSWORD="test12345user"
```

urlib2:

```
def authorization():
import urllib2

gh_url = 'http://pin-im.com/accounts/login/'
gh_user= 'testuser'
gh_pass = 'test12345user'

req = urllib2.Request(gh_url)

password_manager = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_manager.add_password(None, gh_url, gh_user, gh_pass)

auth_manager = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_manager)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_manager)

urllib2.install_opener(opener)

handler = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Grab:

```
def autorization():
g = Grab()
g.setup(post={'username':'testuser', 'Password':'test12345user', 'act': 'submit'})
g.go("http://pin-im.com/accounts/login/")
g.go("http://pin-im.com/user/my-profile/")
print g.response.code
```

Request(i used all methods in Request Lib for authorization, one of them):

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
requests.get('http://pin-im.com/accounts/login/', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('testuser', 'test12345user'))
r. get("http://pin-im.com/user/my-profile/")
r.status_code
```

I'm despair, can you help me login to this site? and what i did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
userData = "Basic " + ("testuser:test12345user").encode("base64").rstrip()
req = urllib2.Request('http://pin-im.com/accounts/login')
req.add_header('Accept', 'application/json')
req.add_header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
req.add_header('Authorization', userData)
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Comment: Hmm... are you try this before posting at all?

Answer (score 0):

This site uses [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) [protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/), so you should get csrftoken cookie and send it back to server with your request:

```
import Cookie
from urllib import urlencode

import httplib2


URL="http://pin-im.com/accounts/login/"
LOGIN="testuser"
PASSWORD="test12345user"

http = httplib2.Http()

response, _ = http.request(URL)

cookies = Cookie.BaseCookie()
cookies.load(response["set-cookie"])
csrftoken = cookies["csrftoken"].value

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
headers['Cookie'] = response['set-cookie']

data = {
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrftoken,
    "username":LOGIN,
    "password": PASSWORD
}

response, _ = http.request(URL, "POST", headers=headers, body=urlencode(data))

response, content = http.request(
    "http://pin-im.com/user/my-profile/",
    "GET",
    headers={'Cookie': response['set-cookie']}
)
print response, content
```

Comment: I tried authorization with this answers, but i didn't login. With Oxyum answer i have status code 302.

Comment: It's expected behavior of that site. You should just get cookies from that answer and use it with all other requests.

I updated code with opening **my-profile** page.